# Python "import random" Error

Tags: python, random

As you may know from my previous posts, I'm learning Python. And this time I have a small error which I think is with this build of Python itself. When using the following:

```
import random
number = random.randint(1,10000)
```

Python gives me this error:

```
File "C\Users\name\Documents\Python\random.py", line 5, in (module)
  print random.random()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Every time I try to run it. Me no understand. Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: The two lines of code I'm trying to run:

```
import random
print random.randint(1,100)
```

That's it. And it gives me the same error.

Comment: Are you importing the module twice?

Comment: You can't call your script the same name. Change it to `my_random.py` or something else.

Comment: @squiguy Thanks, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: @enginefree Nope, just once:

Comment: What does your import statement look like?

Comment: Please post all of your code. After reading your error statement it looks like you are trying to `print random.random()` which does not exist.  Do you mean `print number`?

Comment: @timc I wrote this and it gave me the same error:
import random
print random.randint(1,100) and nothing. Both on separate lines of course

Comment: You probably saved it as another file called `my_random.py` in the same directory. Delete the original `random.py` file that you created, then run `my_random.py`.

Comment: Also, after renaming, remember to delete the compiled `random.pyc` that would have been created previously. The presence of this file in your script directory would have still confusingly caused the same problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By naming your script `random.py`, you've created a naming conflict with the `random` standard library module.

When you try to run your script, the directory containing the script will be added to the start of the module import path.  So when your script does `import random`, you're effectively running a second copy of the script as the `random` module.

When the `random` module runs `import random`, it means that `random.random` will also be a reference to your module.  So when you attempt to call the `random.random()` standard library function, you're actually attempting to call the module object resulting in the error you got.

If you rename your script to something else, the problem should go away.

Comment: I actually think this was the problem. While this actual post didn't help me, it is what I did to fix it, I believe. Answer accepted.

Comment: wow:) after a quite long time of struggling with random module thing
This finally made my day:)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced the same problem. I have renamed my python file from random.py to shuffle.py. This didn't work out. Then I changed the version then it worked. This may help a bit.
Python version : 3.6.7
replace
import random;
to 
import random2;

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer: Change your filename from "random.py" to something else as it is conflicting with random library.

Answer (score -1):

I am using pycharm and I had to take the additional step to import the methods `from random`.   In my case:

```
import random
 from random import choice
```

Answer (score -1):

You can install random2 by following command : pip install random2
Copy the code below :

```
import random2
from random2 import choice,randint

list = [1,2,3,4,5 ]
print(random2.choice(list))
print(random2.randint(1,100))
```

It should work..

Comment: No, _don't_ do this. [That package](https://pypi.org/project/random2/) hasn't been updated in over a decade. Its description also contains typos and unclear descriptions... I wouldn't go anywhere near it.