# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'paInt16'

Tags: python, module, attributes, pyaudio

I have trying to get the latest version of pyaudio to work with jasper on my raspberry pi 2 model B. When I try to get it to run in jasper It has a sample rate issue which I have narrowed down to a pyaudio issue.

When I run the test example:

```
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
            channels=CHANNELS,
            rate=RATE,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
data = stream.read(CHUNK)
frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'paInt16'
```

I've tried re-installing etc with no avail

Comment: What version of python/pyaudio are you using?

Comment: Does everything work if you simply set `FORMAT` equal to 8? This may reek of issues deeper down.

Comment: I now get this issue:  
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PyAudio'

Comment: How did you go about installing pyaudio?

Comment: sudo apt-get install git  
 sudo git clone http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/git/pyaudio.git  
 sudo apt-get install libportaudio0 libportaudio2 libportaudiocpp0 portaudio19-dev  
 sudo apt-get install python-dev  
 cd pyaudio  
 sudo python setup.py install

Comment: if you named your file `pyaudio.py` you are having the same problem as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813164/python-import-random-error

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen's answer is helpful (because my python file is called pyaudio.py....)